# SQL Server - what's the difference between using ISNULL() in front of CONVERT() and within it?

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I got someone else's query to work with and trying to break it down to understand everything.

In SELECT, most of the columns are called like below:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(<column name>,''),100)
```

Does it make a big difference if the ISNULL function was used like this:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,<column name>,100),'')
```

At first look for me it's not a big deal, but maybe someone with more experience will know.

Comment: [Bad Habits to kick: **Declaring VARCHAR without length**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a difference.

When you cast '' as int, you get 0 cast it to varchar and you get '0'

When you cast null as varchar you get null. Isnull will change the value to ''

```
DECLARE @a int = null, @b datetime = null

SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(@a,''),100) colA1,
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@a,100),'') colA2,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(@b,''),100) colB1,
  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@b,100),'') colB2
```

Returns(colA2 and ColB2 are empty varchars):

```
colA1   colA2               colB1               colB2
0                           Jan 1 1900 12:00AM
```

Comment: Isnull will change the value to '' not '0' . and datetime type are good example too

Answer (score 4):

*Note: This is all based on testing*

Running `ISNULL(<variable>, '')` will return the minimum value depending on the data type.

```
DECLARE 
    @intVar     INT,
    @dateVar    DATE,
    @varcharVar VARCHAR(20)

SELECT 
    [INT]       = ISNULL(@intVar, ''), 
    [DATE]      = ISNULL(@dateVar, ''), 
    [VARCHAR]   = ISNULL(@varcharVar, '')
```

Running the above script will return:

```
INT         DATE       VARCHAR
----------- ---------- ----------
0           1900-01-01
```

If you perform `ISNULL` first before the `CONVERT`, it will not produce the expected result:

```
INT        DATE        VARCHAR
---------- ----------- ----------
0          Jan  1 1900
```

On the other hand, if you perform `ISNULL` after the `CONVERT`, it will product the expected result, that is `''`

```
INT        DATE       VARCHAR
---------- ---------- ----------
                                -- These are empty strings('')
```

---

As stated in this [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/sql-server-isnull-returning-1900-01-01-when-field-is-null#comment161330_89945) by Aaron Bertrand, an empty string `''` evaluates to `0`, which implicitly is an integer representing the number of days since `1900-01-01`.